# Congruence numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, reference-request

Having read about [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) I am curious. The article says it shows the number of equivalence relations on a set $n$ with $k$ equivalence classes which makes sense to me from the definition. I am curious, is there any such number/process to acquire the the [congruence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation) count? I realize this would be heavily determined by the operations on but it could possibly exist, couldn't it?

Comment: You'd have to specify the structure, no? It's not clear to me what a congruence relation count would be without reference to any structure.

Comment: I don't reference a particular structure as I want it as generic as possible, preferably one that can be used to as many algebraic structures as possible. If you have one for groups or special cases they'll be of interest though.

Comment: If it comes to groups then you are actually asking for the number of normal subgroups of a group with order $n$ that have order $n:k$. That is not only depending on $n$ and $k$ but also on the groupstructure (e.g. simple? abelian?). So you would get a pseudo Stirlingnumber $S(G)$ where $G$ denotes the group. Not much hope in that direction.